# Cloudinary Image Upload

Tags: file-upload, next.js, cloudinary, image-upload

I am using Cloudinary with NextJS. When I am trying to specify the folder name in sign.js, which will create a signature for my request, I am getting an "Unauthorized" error as a response. But without a folder name, it works fine.

**sign.js** - This is the file responsible for creation of signature.

```js
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;

const sign = async (req, res) => {
  const timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

  const signature = cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request({
    timestamp: timestamp,
    folder: 'product'
  }, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_SECRET);

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json({ signature, timestamp });
};

export default sign;
```

**index.js** - This is the main file.

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {

    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
    const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);
    const [file, setFile] = useState();

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
        setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]))
        setIsFilePicked(true);
    };

    const handleSubmission = async () => {
        const { signature, timestamp } = await getSignature();
        const formData = new FormData();
        const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/upload`
        formData.append('file', selectedFile)
        formData.append("signature", signature);
        formData.append("timestamp", timestamp);
        formData.append("api_key", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_KEY);
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Tailwind-Next</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <div className={styles.main}>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-[50%] mb-5">
                    {selectedFile == null ?
                        <label htmlFor="dropzone-file" className={`flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-bray-800  hover:bg-gray-100 ${styles.dropzone}`}>
                            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-10 h-10 mb-3 text-gray-400" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M7 16a4 4 0 01-.88-7.903A5 5 0 1115.9 6L16 6a5 5 0 011 9.9M15 13l-3-3m0 0l-3 3m3-3v12"></path></svg>
                                <p className="mb-2 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><span className="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</p>
                                <p className="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (MAX. 800x400px)</p>
                            </div>
                            <input id="dropzone-file" type="file" className="hidden" accept="image/*" onChange={changeHandler} />
                        </label> :
                        <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 relative'>
                            <div className={styles.image_wrapper}>
                                <img src={file} className={styles.img_preview} alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>}

                </div>
                <button className="w-[50%] bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-600 rounded" onClick={handleSubmission}>
                    Upload
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    )

}

async function getSignature() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/sign");
    const data = await response.json();
    const { signature, timestamp } = data;
    return { signature, timestamp };
}
```

I tried creating a signature without a folder name, and it worked fine. However, when I attempted to create a signature using the folder name, it returned unauthorized.

Comment: Hi, When generating the signature you need to sign the parameters you use in the upload request. The error response you receive includes a string with the exact parameters that were expected to be signed according to the parameters that were included in the upload request. Looking at the code you provided, the "folder" parameter is not part of the upload request, and therefore the signature isn't valid. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there an example of this, because I'm new to cloudinary and don't know much about it. I went through the documentation as well but was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 13 bad requests and 31 unauthorized requests, I was finally able to resolve the issue.

**sign.js** -  This is the file responsible for creation of signature.

```js
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;

const sign = async (req, res) => {
  const timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

  const signature = cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request({
    timestamp: timestamp,
    folder: 'product'
  }, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_SECRET);

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json({ signature, timestamp });
};

export default sign;
```

**index.js** - This is the main file.

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {

    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
    const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);
    const [file, setFile] = useState();

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
        setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]))
        setIsFilePicked(true);
    };

    const handleSubmission = async () => {
        const { signature, timestamp } = await getSignature();
        const formData = new FormData();
        const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/upload`
        formData.append('file', selectedFile)
        formData.append("signature", signature);
        formData.append("timestamp", timestamp);
        formData.append("api_key", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_KEY);
        formData.append("folder", "product")
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Tailwind-Next</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <div className={styles.main}>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-[50%] mb-5">
                    {selectedFile == null ?
                        <label htmlFor="dropzone-file" className={`flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-bray-800  hover:bg-gray-100 ${styles.dropzone}`}>
                            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-10 h-10 mb-3 text-gray-400" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M7 16a4 4 0 01-.88-7.903A5 5 0 1115.9 6L16 6a5 5 0 011 9.9M15 13l-3-3m0 0l-3 3m3-3v12"></path></svg>
                                <p className="mb-2 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><span className="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</p>
                                <p className="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (MAX. 800x400px)</p>
                            </div>
                            <input id="dropzone-file" type="file" className="hidden" accept="image/*" onChange={changeHandler} />
                        </label> :
                        <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 relative'>
                            <div className={styles.image_wrapper}>
                                <img src={file} className={styles.img_preview} alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>}

                </div>
                <button className="w-[50%] bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-600 rounded" onClick={handleSubmission}>
                    Upload
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

async function getSignature() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/sign");
    const data = await response.json();
    const { signature, timestamp } = data;
    return { signature, timestamp };
}
```